# Make specific Style of comments

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

In VScode is there is a shortcut to make a comment/header like this

> /*------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ## site-header
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------*/

How can I do that?
If I need some kind of extension do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [custom snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) for this. Then you can [setup a keybinding for the snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets).

Here's an example keybinding for such a snippet:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "/*------------------------------------------------------------\n${TM_FILENAME}\n------------------------------------------------------------*/"
  }
}
```

If you want the header to always be inserted at the top of the file, you need to [create a simple extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api)

Answer (score 0):

Another better approach which is actually different from what I asked, but kinda cool one.
There is a VSCode extension named "Better Comments" which allow you to add comments with the colour code.
[Link For the same extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments)

[Sample Screenshot for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhraH.png)